# add a select to filter a select from a foreign key

Tags: django, django-admin

Django 1.9

My models

```
class Category(models.Model):
    categoryid = models.AutoField(db_column='CategoryID', primary_key=True)
    categoryname = models.CharField('Name', db_column='CategoryName', unique=True, max_length=25)
    categorycode = models.CharField('Code', db_column='CategoryCode', unique=True, max_length=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.categoryname

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'category'

class Subcategory(models.Model):
    subcategoryid = models.AutoField(db_column='SubCategoryID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    subcategoryname = models.CharField(db_column='SubCategoryName', unique=True, max_length=25)  # Field name made lowercase.
    subcategorycode = models.CharField(db_column='SubCategoryCode', unique=True, max_length=1)  # Field name made lowercase.
    categoryid = models.ForeignKey(Category, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='CategoryID')  # Field name made lowercase.

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subcategoryname

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'subcategory'

 class Product(models.Model):
     productid = models.IntegerField(db_column='ProductID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
     productname = models.CharField('Name', db_column='ProductName', max_length=30)  # Field name made lowercase.
    reference = models.CharField('Reference', db_column='Reference', unique=True, max_length=5)  # Field name made lowercase.
    subcategoryid = models.ForeignKey('Subcategory', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='SubCategoryID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    providers = models.ManyToManyField(Provider, through='ProviderProduct')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.productname

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'product'
```

With this model on the admin panel I have automatically a dropdownlist to select the subcategory (has a foreign key of subcategory)
But I would like to add another dropdownlist with the category, and once the category is selected, the subcategory dropdownlist is populated according to the category chosen.
It is possible ?
And of course, when I edit a product, the category dropdownlist is selected on the right category

Thanks.

Comment: You can try to use `TabulatInline` in your admin

Comment: I already use `TabularInLine` for `ManyToMany` relationship, but I can't figure out how it can help me with my question. Did I miss something ?

Comment: So, finally, I have decided to use django-smart-select. So new question, why this must have feature doesn't become a Django core feature?